# Why is my loop in a loop only printing half the list length?

Tags: python, loops

I have a list with 60 elements, CashFlow. I am building a new list, ListNPV, where each element is the result of an equation using every element in the original CashFlow. After adding the sum to the new list, I delete one element from the original CashFlow.

When I run this, it completes exactly half the list, so 30 values. I doubled the code to make sure, and it results in 15 / 45 down from 30 / 30. I want 0 / 60. Using Canopy.

```
 for payment in CashFlow:  
    NPV = 0 
    for i in range(len(CashFlow)):    
        NPV += CashFlow[i] / (1+MonthlyInterest)**i
        NPV = round (NPV, 0)
    ListNPV.append(NPV)
    CashFlow.remove(payment)
print 'CashFlow = ', CashFlow
print 'ListNPV =', ListNPV
```

Comment: What language are you talking about?  It *looks* like Python, but...  Also, why do you feel that this is the best approach to do this?  You're mutating the same list that you're iterating over, which is a bad practice in many cases.

Comment: It's Python, using the new environment Canopy. This was the best thing I could come up with, would appreciated other ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), you should not change a list you are iterating over:

> If you need to modify the sequence you are iterating over while inside
>   the loop (for example to duplicate selected items), it is recommended
>   that you first make a copy. Iterating over a sequence does not
>   implicitly make a copy.

In this case you don't even use the loop variable, `payment`, so you can just clean up the loops a little. This should work:

```
N = len(CashFlow)
for j in range(N):
    NPV = 0 
    for i in range(j, N):
        NPV += CashFlow[i] / (1+MonthlyInterest) ** (i - j)
        NPV = round (NPV, 0)
    ListNPV.append(NPV)

print 'CashFlow = ', CashFlow
print 'ListNPV =', ListNPV
```

Comment: The iteration with `j=1` and `i=0` will result in the negative power of the `(1+MonthlyInterest) ** (i - j)` part of the equation which was not there in the OP. 

EDIT: Oh I see that is not possible, great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Due to following line

```
 CashFlow.remove(payment)
```

Above line impacts the length of CashFlow.Remove this line, and all your iteration will be done. After that you can remove the cashflow list seperately.

Comment: Right - but I need to calculate a new addition to ListNPV based on the CashFlow minus one element.

Comment: For that, copy all the CashFlow content into another collection, and then loop on one collection which should remain unchanged, and modify other collection and calculate on that. Looping and modifying same collection causes cases hard to debug and fix.